# sharepoint 2010 - how to add a loginview conditional statment to a publishing page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within my Publishing site for share point 2010, I have a publishing page that shows content on there. but the content will need to change if the user is logged in.  Is there an easy way to directly add a loginview conditional statement to a specific share point publishing page?

For example, I want to add this directly onto my publishing page...

```
<div class="customTopLeft"> 
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server"> 
<AnonymousTemplate>
<p>content for anonymous user</p>
</AnonymousTemplate>
<LoggedInTemplate>
<p>content for logged in members</p>
</LoggedInTemplate>
<asp:LoginView>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: One way to do it would be to place the content in a content editor web part and apply audience targeting to it for authenticated users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by placing my asp Loginview tag in my master template, which will allow various actions to occur to any page, based on ID's and Classes, all with the help of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to add a Security Trimmed Control, http://fusionovation.com/post/2008/09/18/security-trimmed-controls-in-sharepoint.aspx

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="AddListItems">
Place your content here
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```